# How to set value of specific inputs with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to set values that I'm getting from the backend and display them in my text inputs in the front. I have multiple inputs and I want to set the value of a specific input

```
const stampToDate = response[i].cra.date;
const dayOnInput = moment(stampToDate).format('DD MMM YYYY');
const o = moment(stampToDate).day();
for (let x = 0; x < $('.App input').length; x += 1) {
  if (x === o) {
    console.log($('.App input')[x - 1]));
  }
}
```

what I want to do is something like this

```
($('.App input')[x - 1].val() = response[i].myvalue
```

any ideas please ?

Comment: Try using val(value), the overload of val(). http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2

Comment: it worked Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each day has an input

```
$('input.App').eq(o-1).val(response[i].myvalue)
```

Comment: i used $('input.App').eq(o-1).value indtead of .val() and it worked thank you

Comment: That is not lilkely. There are no "value" on a jQuery element - to use value you would need `$('input.App').eq(o-1)[0].value`